# Determine whether there exists at least one path between two nodes in constant time

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, path

In a directed graph, Is it possible to determine whether there exists at least one path between two predefined nodes in constant time? If I use adjacency matrix data structure will it be useful?

Please suggest me what I am missing, what I need to learn. If there is no standard algorithm can you explain some solution for me.

Comment: Yes not in constant time but O(n * n) is possible which may not give you optimal solution. It is not C, C++ question Read BFS, DFS etcs. read this: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-if-there-is-a-path-between-two-vertices-in-a-given-graph/

Answer (score 1):

Well, without pre-processing it cannot be done in constant time, you are bounded by the shortest path between these nodes to find the shortest path, and if no such path exists - it might decay to the size of the graph.

If you allow pre-processing, you can construct Strongly Connected Components graph (let it be G'), lexicographically sort it, and add an indication of all pairs (v',u') if there is a path from v' to u' on G'.

On query time you can search for the `v'` that contains `v`, and `u'` that contains `u`. and check if there is a path from `v'` to `u'`, the answer will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you pre-process the graph with [Kruskal's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm), then it's subsequently possible to determine whether two nodes are connected in constant time.  The algorithm will generate one or more sets of connected nodes.  Two nodes that are in the same set are connected by one or more paths.  Nodes in disjoint sets are not connected.

If you aren't allowed to pre-process the graph, then the answer is "No".